# Pull Images & Thumbnails from a Folder Through PHP

Tags: php, html, design-patterns, web, glob

I'm trying to generate images on my website by pulling a thumbnail from one folder and the actual image from another. I have no idea what I am doing. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$thumbdirname = "images/thumbs/";
$imgdirname = "images/";
$mainimages = glob($imgdirname."*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
$imagethumbs = glob($thumbdirname."*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($imagethumbs as $image) {

echo '<a class="imageLink" href="$mainimages" data-lightbox="logo" data-title="Vivid Logo"><img src="'.$image.'"</a> ';

}
?>
```

I know that it will not work with just "$mainimages" for href, but I haven't been able to figure out what to put there. As is, it will pull up the right thumbnail, but not link to the full associated image.

I tried to put another foreach statement in, but I get four results from my two pictures (and their thumbnails). Which makes sense sense it is showing one of each combination:

(img1,thumb1),(img1,thumb2),(img2,thumb1),(img2,thumb2)

How should I change this to get it playing nicely?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be outputting from `$mainimages` so I'm going to ignore this for now. 
You PHP code seems to be OK from initial glance. Only thing that is a bit iffy is that you are not closing you image tag.

If that does not help try counting the image array/object.

If that returns `0` try the below code.

```
// Find all files in that folder
$files = glob('images/gallery1/*');

// Display images
foreach($files as $file) {
   echo '<img src="' . $file . '" />';
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This works, but I still need to have two files pulled from their directories and their paths placed in the echo'd line.